# How to operate the plugin of munin membyuser?

Tags: debian, munin, graph

I can not run this plugin **membyuser**

The graph is not shown
eg [screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xbwm2kh2fwmbvaa/r7HKY0ERnV#/)

**munin-node** is configured as follows:

```
/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
...
[membyuser]
env.USERS user1 user2 user3 user4
...
```

**munin-graph.log** says:

```
[RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/host/membyuser-week.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory
[RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/host/membyuser-day.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory
[RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/host/membyuser-year.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory
```

I verified that the directories exist and are writable. This is not the problem.

I launched **debug** and says:

```
 [DEBUG] Node name: membyuser
 [DEBUG] Expanding specials for membyuser: "root","others".
 [DEBUG] Checking field lengths for membyuser: "".
 [DEBUG] Treating fields "root","others".
 [DEBUG] Processing field "root" [root].
 DEBUG: single_value: Checking field "root".
 DEBUG: single_value: Checking field "others".
 [DEBUG] service myhost :: myhost :: membyuser has 2 elements.
 [DEBUG] RRD name / filename: root / /var/lib/munin/--g.rrd
 [DEBUG] Drawing field "root".
 [DEBUG] Processing field "others" [others].
 [DEBUG] service myhost :: myhost :: membyuser has 2 elements.
 [DEBUG] RRD name / filename: others / /var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd
 [DEBUG] Drawing field "others".


rrdtool 'graph' '--font' \
    'DEFAULT:0:DejaVuSans' \
    '--font' \
    'LEGEND:7:DejaVuSansMono' \
    '-W' \
    'Munin 1.4.5' \
    '/var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-month.png' \
    '--title' \
    'Memory usage, by user - by month' \
    '--start' \
    '-33d' \
    '--base' \
    '1000' \
    '-r' \
    '--lower-limit' \
    '0' \
    '--vertical-label' \
    'KB' \
    '--height' \
    '175' \
    '--width' \
    '400' \
    '--imgformat' \
    'PNG' \
    '--units-exponent' \
    '0' \
    'DEF:aothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:gothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'DEF:aroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:groot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'CDEF:croot=groot,POP,UNKN' \
    'COMMENT:      ' \
    'COMMENT: Cur\:' \
    'COMMENT:Min\:' \
    'COMMENT:Avg\:' \
    'COMMENT:Max\:  \j' \
    'AREA:groot#00CC00:root   ' \
    'GPRINT:croot:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iroot:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:groot:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aroot:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'CDEF:cothers=gothers' \
    'STACK:gothers#0066B3:others ' \
    'GPRINT:cothers:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iothers:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:gothers:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aothers:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'COMMENT:Last update\: Fri Mar 15 20\:15\:05 2013\r' \
    '--end' \
    '1363370400'
 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-month.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory


rrdtool 'graph' '--font' \
    'DEFAULT:0:DejaVuSans' \
    '--font' \
    'LEGEND:7:DejaVuSansMono' \
    '-W' \
    'Munin 1.4.5' \
    '/var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-week.png' \
    '--title' \
    'Memory usage, by user - by week' \
    '--start' \
    '-8d' \
    '--base' \
    '1000' \
    '-r' \
    '--lower-limit' \
    '0' \
    '--vertical-label' \
    'KB' \
    '--height' \
    '175' \
    '--width' \
    '400' \
    '--imgformat' \
    'PNG' \
    '--units-exponent' \
    '0' \
    'DEF:aothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:gothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'DEF:aroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:groot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'CDEF:croot=groot,POP,UNKN' \
    'COMMENT:      ' \
    'COMMENT: Cur\:' \
    'COMMENT:Min\:' \
    'COMMENT:Avg\:' \
    'COMMENT:Max\:  \j' \
    'AREA:groot#00CC00:root   ' \
    'GPRINT:croot:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iroot:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:groot:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aroot:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'CDEF:cothers=gothers' \
    'STACK:gothers#0066B3:others ' \
    'GPRINT:cothers:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iothers:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:gothers:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aothers:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'COMMENT:Last update\: Fri Mar 15 20\:15\:05 2013\r' \
    '--end' \
    '1363374000'
 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-week.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory


rrdtool 'graph' '--font' \
    'DEFAULT:0:DejaVuSans' \
    '--font' \
    'LEGEND:7:DejaVuSansMono' \
    '-W' \
    'Munin 1.4.5' \
    '/var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-day.png' \
    '--title' \
    'Memory usage, by user - by day' \
    '--start' \
    '-30h' \
    '--base' \
    '1000' \
    '-r' \
    '--lower-limit' \
    '0' \
    '--vertical-label' \
    'KB' \
    '--height' \
    '175' \
    '--width' \
    '400' \
    '--imgformat' \
    'PNG' \
    '--units-exponent' \
    '0' \
    'DEF:aothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:gothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'DEF:aroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:groot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'CDEF:croot=groot,POP,UNKN' \
    'COMMENT:      ' \
    'COMMENT: Cur\:' \
    'COMMENT:Min\:' \
    'COMMENT:Avg\:' \
    'COMMENT:Max\:  \j' \
    'AREA:groot#00CC00:root   ' \
    'GPRINT:croot:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iroot:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:groot:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aroot:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'CDEF:cothers=gothers' \
    'STACK:gothers#0066B3:others ' \
    'GPRINT:cothers:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iothers:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:gothers:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aothers:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'COMMENT:Last update\: Fri Mar 15 20\:15\:05 2013\r' \
    '--end' \
    '1363374900'
 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-day.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory


rrdtool 'graph' '--font' \
    'DEFAULT:0:DejaVuSans' \
    '--font' \
    'LEGEND:7:DejaVuSansMono' \
    '-W' \
    'Munin 1.4.5' \
    '/var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-year.png' \
    '--title' \
    'Memory usage, by user - by year' \
    '--start' \
    '-400d' \
    '--base' \
    '1000' \
    '-r' \
    '--lower-limit' \
    '0' \
    '--vertical-label' \
    'KB' \
    '--height' \
    '175' \
    '--width' \
    '400' \
    '--imgformat' \
    'PNG' \
    '--units-exponent' \
    '0' \
    'DEF:aothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:gothers=/var/lib/munin/myhost/myhost-membyuser-others-g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'DEF:aroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MAX' \
    'DEF:iroot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:MIN' \
    'DEF:groot=/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd:42:AVERAGE' \
    'CDEF:croot=groot,POP,UNKN' \
    'COMMENT:      ' \
    'COMMENT: Cur\:' \
    'COMMENT:Min\:' \
    'COMMENT:Avg\:' \
    'COMMENT:Max\:  \j' \
    'AREA:groot#00CC00:root   ' \
    'GPRINT:croot:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iroot:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:groot:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aroot:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'CDEF:cothers=gothers' \
    'STACK:gothers#0066B3:others ' \
    'GPRINT:cothers:LAST:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:iothers:MIN:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:gothers:AVERAGE:%6.2lf' \
    'GPRINT:aothers:MAX:%6.2lf\j' \
    'COMMENT:Last update\: Fri Mar 15 20\:15\:05 2013\r' \
    '--end' \
    '1363305600'
 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /var/cache/munin/www/myhost/myhost/membyuser-year.png : opening '/var/lib/munin/--g.rrd': No such file or directory
 Graphed service : membyuser (0.01 sec * 4)
```

I have no idea how to fix ..

Answer (score 0):

On the screenshot I see you are using Munin v. 1.4.5 . Very old version.
I'm using 2.x.x, and I do not have membyuser plugin.
Maybe problem is in this plugin with incorrect definitions.
I see some version of this plugin on url:
http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/munin-contrib/plugins/system/membyuser

But I recommend you upgrade munin, because old versions are very buggy.